# Kubernetes how to handle thumbnails and png pictures

Tags: image, kubernetes

We are trying to create an image of a Python application that has .PNG pictures. How do you specify the YAML to access those pictures?

We looked at the YAML for the different settings for "kind", but didn't see any type for PNG/pictures.
What is the YAML for Kubernetes that makes a picture file available?

Comment: "Image file" isn't a Kubernetes construct at all.  What are you hoping will happen with this file?  If you're trying to build a Docker image, can you just `COPY` the file into the image?

Answer (score 0):

Images and .PNG pictures do not related to your YAML in Kubernetes.
In K8S, you just need to specify the relevant image that you are using. I guess that you have an app (Python code) that will load them.

Answer (score 0):

A png file can be represented as base64 encoded Ascii, you could get this out of your application as an application property/env value and stick it as an [Annotation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/annotations/) to your yaml file, or handle it with [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/).

For example this is a stackoverflow icon png file:

[image: so-icon]

Its base64 representation (truncated):

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAJ4A...ErkJggg==
```

In your yaml file:

```
..
  metadata:
    name: whatever
    labels:
      ..
    annotations:
      my-so-icon-file: |
        data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAJ4A...ErkJggg==
```